# How to tell regex not to match a group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was doing some experiment with regex in my learning process.

Input is : `I am ironman and I was batman and I will be superman`

I want to match all words except the word `batman`

I tried `[^(batman)]+` but it doesn't match characters `a,b,m,n,t` anywhere in string

How can I achieve it?

Comment: you will only see tricky regex for exclusions, and more tricky in javascript.

Comment: please suggest some tricky ones too.. I want to learn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several ways are possible:

with a negative lookahead assertion `(?!...)` *(not followed by)*:

```
\b(?!batman\b)\w+
```

with a capture group (you must take in account only the capture group 1):

```
\b(?:batman\b|(\w+))
```

Why your pattern doesn't work:

You wrote `[^(batman)]` but a character class is only a collection of characters without order, you can't describe substrings inside it. It is the same than `[^abmnt()]`

Comment: How would you *use* those to do what theOP asked?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: a simple match as the OP is trying to do.

Comment: `"I am ironman and I was batman and I will be superman".match(/\b(?!batman\b)\w+/g)`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: The OP didn't show what he was doing. Code is worth 1024 words, and 10240 assumptions. YOU's post shows it works, though, which is pretty darned cool.

Answer (score 4):

- It's good you're learning regex but this is overkill as you can easily leverage javascript's vast supernatural powers.
- It will be *faster* and *in most cases* **readable** than the equivalent the regex.
- Exclude Batman at your own cost :)
- Here's how you do it, *without regex*. I'm sure someone will post regex answer too.

Okay, enough of bullshit, here's the code:

```
var words = input.split(" ").filter(function(str){
    return str.toLowerCase() !== "batman";
});
```

Comment: Only works in ES5-supporting browsers, incidentally.

Comment: That's a nice workaround.. but I was more interested in regex patterns.. I will keep this in mind for bigger problems.. thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the discard technique. For instance, you can use this pattern:

```
batman|(\w+)
```

Then you will have the words stored in the capturing group.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW9gE3/1)**

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, words in green are captured using capturing groups while `batman` in blue is discarded.

Match information:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-1]   `I`
MATCH 2
1.  [2-4]   `am`
MATCH 3
1.  [5-12]  `ironman`
MATCH 4
1.  [13-16] `and`
MATCH 5
1.  [17-18] `I`
MATCH 6
1.  [19-22] `was`
MATCH 7
1.  [30-33] `and`
MATCH 8
1.  [34-35] `I`
MATCH 9
1.  [36-40] `will`
MATCH 10
1.  [41-43] `be`
MATCH 11
1.  [44-52] `superman`
```

Another example of discard pattern can be if you want to discard `batman` and `superman`, so you can use:

```
batman|superman|(\w+)
```

[Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JIThjUlSzEUpuSRe)
 does a good job showing this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @rocky thanks for +1, the regex technique is the best trick to discard the patterns you want

Comment: @rocky btw, have just updated with one more example so you can see it better